# How to proof existence in COQ?

Tags: coq

I am quite new to Coq and I am trying to proof the following lemma (with the Reals library):

```
forall (An : nat -> R) (a : R),  Un_cv An a -> Un_cv (fun i : nat => An i - a) 0.
```

Now, I get stuck when I try to find a suitable N such that for all n >= N the sequence converges. I know how to do it by hand, but I do not know how to program this into Coq.

This is my proof so far:

```
Proof.
  intros An a A_cv.
  unfold Un_cv. unfold Un_cv in A_cv.
  intros eps eps_pos.
  unfold R_dist. unfold R_dist in A_cv.
```

And I am left with:

```
1 subgoal
An : nat -> R
a : R
A_cv : forall eps : R,
       eps > 0 -> exists N : nat, forall n : nat, (n >= N)%nat -> Rabs (An n - a) < eps
eps : R
eps_pos : eps > 0
______________________________________(1/1)
exists N : nat, forall n : nat, (n >= N)%nat -> Rabs (An n - a - 0) < eps
```

And the problem is that I do not know how to get rid of the "exists N".

Is this even possible? And if it is, can anyone help me?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally, to eliminate `exists N` in coq, you need to instantiate it with a term. If you were to write this out by hand, you would probably write something like, "since `An` converges, there is some `N` such that ..." and then you would use that `N` in your proof.

To do this in Coq, you will need to use the `destruct` tactic on `A_cv`.  Once you have this `N`, you can use it to instantiate and continue like you'd expect.

Full proof for reference:

```
Lemma some_lemma : forall (An : nat -> R) (a : R),  Un_cv An a -> Un_cv (fun i : nat => An i - a) 0.
Proof.
  intros An a A_cv.
  unfold Un_cv. unfold Un_cv in A_cv.
  intros eps eps_pos.
  unfold R_dist. unfold R_dist in A_cv.
  destruct (A_cv eps eps_pos) as [N HN].
  exists N; intro.
  rewrite Rminus_0_r.
  apply HN.
Qed.
```

Comment: What is likable with this example is that you use the same ideas as in a plain mathematical proof.

Comment: Thanks for the quick and helpful reply!